# Относительный путь к файлу на localhost

Tags: apache, gulp, localhost, link, mamp

В проекте все "линки" прописаны относительно корня сайта -

в index.php:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/css/reset.css"/>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css"/>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles-media.css"/>
```

При сборке проекта Gulp-ом + MAMP (путь проекта - `MAMP/htdocs/polissya.in/`) в консоле отображаются ошибки:

```
(index):7 GET http://localhost:8002/css/reset.css 
(index):8 GET http://localhost:8002/css/styles.css 
(index):9 GET http://localhost:8002/css/styles-media.css
```

URL в браузере - `http://localhost:8002/polissya.in/build/` - почему же оно берет линки не относительно этого URL, а относительно `http://localhost:8002/`? Путь же должен быть таким - `http://localhost:8002/polissya.in/build/css/reset.css`?

Если прописать к примеру не `href="/css/reset.css"/>`, а  `href="css/reset.css"/>` то все подтягивается нормально - но нужно сохранить именно такие пути как есть, так как в проекте есть еще много PHP "конструкций" именно с такими путями.

Если поместить содержимое папки 'build' в корень `MAMP/htdocs/` то все начинает работать так как пути "сходятся" (но такой вариант мало приемлем и хочу все-таки разобраться). На хостинге тоже все нормально работает.

Подскажите, пожалуйста "в какую сторону смотреть" для решения проблемы.

Comment: все css должны быть на одной "волне" с index.php, если хочешь сохранить пути то создай что-то типа AssetBundle и подтягивай относительно <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/css/reset.css"/>

Comment: Спасибо за ответ - но хотелось бы разобраться именно с localhost-ом, если есть такая возможность